# Protractor can't find element by binding $ctrl

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a little experience using Protractor. Using by.css, by.name and by.id I can select elements but somehow my tests are failing when using by.binding.

Am I missing something obvious?

View:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.speaker.firstName" maxlength="60" />
```

Protractor test:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
let firstName = element(by.binding('$ctrl.speaker.firstName'));
browser.driver.wait(EC.presenceOf(firstName), 2000, 'find element firstname');
firstName.sendKeys('Bill');
```

Testresult:

```
Failures:
1) Speakers should ..
  Message:
    Failed: find element firstname
    Wait timed out after 2003ms
  Stack:
    TimeoutError: find element firstname
```

*There are some SO q&a's but they don't help me in finding whats wrong.*

### Update

Ok, this was pretty obvious `by.binding` should be `by.model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **by.model()** method.

```
let firstName = element(by.model('$ctrl.speaker.firstName'));
```